# Maximal Volume of the Solid of Revolution of a Rectangle Constrained by an Ordinate Set

Tags: calculus, analysis

This is question Number 20 from Tom M. Apostol's Calculus Chapter 4 Section 4.21:

> A cylinder is obtained by revolving a rectangle about the x-axis, the base of the rectangle lying on the x-axis and the entire rectangle lying in the region between the curve $y=\frac{x}{x^2+1}$ and the x-axis.  Find the maximum possible volume of the cylinder.

The below is my attempt at a solution:

A simple graph in desmos to illustrate the situation: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hxktkpibfs

Since the cylinder is a solid of revolution, we may restrict our consideration to only the x-y plane for if we have found the maximal rectangle the cylinder which results is also maximal.  Because this is a rectangle, we may parameterize it based on x.  If (x,0) is a vertex, then $(x,\frac{x}{x^2+1})$ is also a vertex.  The y-coordinate of the third vertex must be equal to that of the second (because this is the side of a rectangle).  Hence if the rectangle is $t-x$ long, then we must also have the points $(t,0)$ and $(t,\frac{t}{t^2+1})$ where $$\frac{t}{t^2+1}=\frac{x}{x^2+1}\tag{1}$$  The two solutions to (1) are $t=x$ and $t=\frac{1}{x}$.  Let's only consider $t=\frac{1}{x}$.  Hence we may construct an area function f(x) which we will later maximize. Let$$f(x) = (\frac{1}{x}-x)(\frac{x}{x^2+1})\tag{2}$$ It should suffice to only consider $x\in(0,1]$ since if $x<1$ 1/x would cover everything else.  Then f represents its area.
Hence,
$$f'(x)=\frac{-4x}{(x^2+1)^2}\tag{3}$$ which is negative for all $x>0$.  Therefore f is strictly decreasing.  Hence the greatest area attainable is where x is closest to 0, which makes sense intuitively since the curve y has a horizontal asymptote of 0.  But somehow the correct answer is $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Thank you all in advance for having the patience to read this.  I have no idea where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rectangle with maximum area does not necessarily imply that the corresponding cylinder's volume is maximized, because while the area of a rectangle with dimensions $w$ and $h$ is $wh$, the corresponding volume of the cylinder would be $V = \pi w^2 h$.  Maximizing $wh$ does not mean $V$ will be maximized.  Another way to conceptualize this is that increasing $w$ increases the rectangle's area linearly, but the volume of the cylinder increases *quadratically*.  This is where your error lies.

First, observe that $$f(x) = \frac{x}{x^2 + 1} = \frac{1}{x + \frac{1}{x}}, \quad x > 0,$$
so that $f(\frac{1}{x}) = f(x)$ for all $x > 0$.  So if the rectangle has a vertex at $(x,0)$, then the other three vertices must be located at
$$(x,f(x)), (\tfrac{1}{x}, f(\tfrac{1}{x})), (\tfrac{1}{x}, 0).$$
Hence assume without loss of generality that $0 < x < 1/x$, or equivalently, $0 < x < 1$.  We then have the volume of the cylinder as
$$V(x) = \pi f(x)^2 \left(\frac{1}{x} - x\right) = \pi \frac{x(1-x^2)}{(1+x^2)^2}.$$  Consequently, $V$ is maximized for some critical point satisfying
$$0 = \frac{dV}{dx} = \pi \frac{1-6x^2+x^4}{(1+x^2)^3} = \pi \frac{(x^2+2x-1)(x^2-2x-1)}{(1+x^2)^3}, \quad x \in (0,1).$$
Hence
$$x = \sqrt{2} - 1$$
is the only such critical point, and the resulting volume is
$$V(\sqrt{2} - 1) = \frac{\pi}{4}$$
as claimed.

Comment: Thank you very much for the explanation.  It seemed to me rather counterintuitive at first that a rod of almost infinite length should not be the maximal cylinder.  It makes more sense now.  Have a splendid day.